# Change the name of a SharePoint 2007 app server machine

Tags: iis

I have an Microsoft SharePoint / Project 2007 environment set up on two VM servers:

- APP01 Windows Server 2008 R2 / IIS 7 / SharePoint Server2007  SP3 / Project 2007 SP3
- DB01 Windows Server 2008 R2 / SQL Server 2008 R2

I have SharePoint Central Admin / Project Server / PWA already set up and configured.  We had the server name changed from `APP01` to `APP02`, and are experiencing the following behavior

- I can ping `APP02`, but can no longer ping `APP01`
- If I navigate to `//APP02/PWA/default.aspx` I receive the following error:

An unexpected error has occurred. 
Troubleshoot issues with Windows SharePoint Services.

However, if I navigate to `//APP01/PWA/default.aspx`, PWA loads properly.

Why is `//app02/PWA/default.aspx` not loading PWA, but the old URL is?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is: Why is //app02/PWA/default.aspx not loading PWA, but the old URL is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming a SharePoint 2007 server is **not supported** by the platform. You just *can't do this*.

Note that while there *are* directions how “safely” rename a SharePoint 2007 server around on the internet, this just usually causes a lot more pain than gain and frequently doesn't work at all at the end of the day.

The only officially supported and safe (=working) way to “change” the name of a SharePoint 2007 server is:

1. a fresh install on another machine,
2. extending the farm to this new server,
3. removing the old server from the farm and
4. decomissioning the old machine.

That's the way the cookie crumbles.